# Tomcat has been started on the cloud server, but the port is not occupied

Tags: tomcat

Tomcat logs are fine, but it's not listening to the port, and the Tomcat interface cannot be opened in the browser, showing a connection refused error

I've tried modifying the environment variables and then editing the server.xml by adding the 'address' attribute, then restarting the server, but it didn't work.

Comment: The question does not provide enough information. Here are some questions that come to my mind when reading this. What was the programming language of your application (Java? Kotlin? something else?)? How did you package it (Maven? Gradle?). In what directory did you put your app? What configurations did you do into  your Tomcat server (context.xml? users and passwords?)?